# How to remove elements from an array using values stored in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have two arrays

```
var a = ['tayyar', '14march' ];
```

and

```
b = [{

    "feedsource": "tayyar",  
    "hash": "46cc3d067df1ea7877140c67b60e9a7a"
}, {

    "feedsource": "elmarada",
    "hash": "a9fb75f2aa4771945ec597ecf9ae49ea"
}, {

    "feedsource": "14march",
    "hash": "fce7a6a87b53358c4be47507b0dc327b"
}, {

    "feedsource": "tayyar",    
    "hash": "b85d2a9c22ac4831477de15ba24b4ac5"
}]
```

I want to remove objects from b whose feedsources are not defined in a.

So far I have tried

```
 b.forEach(function(e) {    

                            var indexVal = b.indexOf(e);

                            if(a.indexOf(e.feedsource) ==-1){

                                 console.log(e.feedsource);

                                 b.splice(indexVal,1);

                             }                                                                          
                        });
```

But it doesnt seems to work and I still see the elements that shouldn't be there as well as elements that should be there getting removed. What am I doing wrong in my function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better solution would be to not alter the original array, but instead creating a new, filtered array. Luckily, JavaScript provides [`.filter()`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/filter) to help you with that!

```
var c = b.filter(function(el) {
    // Only keep those where the following is true
    return a.indexOf(el.feedsource) > 0;
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind this if it works. let me give it a shot and see if this works.

Comment: Worth noting that if you are supporting old IE, you will need a polyfill for this.  Can find one here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: @Paddy We're in 2015. If he needs to support old IE, he knows his workflow is bound to be abnormal. And in all case, may God have mercy upon his soul.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - there are quite a few of us around constrained by clients :)  It's still something worth noting.

Comment: I am not supporting old IE so this shouldnt be a problem and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

Create a filtered array with lodash [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter):

```
_.filter(b, function(item) {
    return _.includes(a, item.feedsource);
});
```

Mutate the existing array with lodash [remove()](https://lodash.com/docs#remove):

```
_.remove(b, function(item) {
    return _.includes(a, item.feedsource) === false;
});
```